# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'

Tags: python, api, photoshop-script

I have been trying to use **photoshop-python-api** but I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yash.sinha/PycharmProjects/PhotoshopPythonAPI/api.py", line 2, in <module>
    import photoshop.api as ps
  File "/Users/yash.sinha/PycharmProjects/PhotoshopPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/photoshop/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from photoshop.session import Session
  File "/Users/yash.sinha/PycharmProjects/PhotoshopPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/photoshop/session.py", line 31, in <module>
    from photoshop.api import (
  File "/Users/yash.sinha/PycharmProjects/PhotoshopPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/photoshop/api/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .action_descriptor import ActionDescriptor
  File "/Users/yash.sinha/PycharmProjects/PhotoshopPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/photoshop/api/action_descriptor.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import Photoshop
  File "/Users/yash.sinha/PycharmProjects/PhotoshopPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/photoshop/api/_core.py", line 6, in <module>
    import winreg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'
```

I did my research on **winreg** and I found out that it is a Windows Register. Am I getting this error because I am using a Mac? I have python 3.8.2 on my system.
Help.

Comment: I quickly looked at the source on github and they do have an `import winreg` statement in there. Presumably this api is written for Windows clients only. You could open an issue on their repository.

Comment: There is a related question on their Github on using it on Linux: https://github.com/loonghao/photoshop-python-api/issues/46#issuecomment-755863928 ("*This API is connected to Photoshop through [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model) so this API cannot be used in linux.*").